# How do I insert a wordpress post with '&' in the title

Tags: wordpress, wp-insert-post

If I programmatically add a wordpress post with `wp_insert_post` and the title contains a `&` the `&` is converted to a `&amp;`

For example: `Tips & Tricks` becomes `Tips &amp; Tricks`

My only working solution is to do a `$wpdb->update` with the post title after the `wp_insert_post`. The parameters for the title are passed 1:1.

Is there a better way?